# Black space during animation in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I'm using animation in LinearLayout in order to show and hide right pane. The layout consist of two elements: a map and right panel. When panel hides map immediately changes its size and then animation appears. Its OK.

But when the panel is showing the map shrinks immediately too therefore black space is shown when panel slides and it looks ugly.

The markup as follows:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <MapView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                  android:id="@+id/map_view"
                                  android:layout_above="@id/bottom_panel"
                                  android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_panel"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_weight="3">
        <!-- Panel content -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the picture of what's going on during animation:
[image: Animation]
Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why inner LinearLayout ?

Comment: What do you mean? Why do I need inner linear layout? I need it for panel content.

Comment: ok, and you Animation looks like ?

Comment: Like shown on the picture. Panel slides but when it slides black space appears for ~0.5s.

Comment: i mean your Animation code

Comment: There is no code behind for animation. I've just put this flag in XML `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`. There is just toggle button with on click handler `public void onClick(View v) { if(panel.getVisibility() == View.GONE) panel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }`